# Singleton with static inner class and double-checked locking

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I am reading about Singleton design pattern and evaluating different implementations. I have doubt with the below implementations:

**A. Singleton Implementation with static inner class**

```
public class SingletonWithStaticClass {

private SingletonWithStaticClass(){}

private static class SingletonInnerClass{
    public static SingletonWithStaticClass INSTANCE = new SingletonWithStaticClass();

}

public static SingletonWithStaticClass getInstance(){
    return SingletonInnerClass.INSTANCE;
}
```

}

**B. Singleton double checked locking**

```
public class SingletonWithDoubleCheck {
private static SingletonWithDoubleCheck INSTANCE = null;

private SingletonWithDoubleCheck(){
    if(INSTANCE != null){
        throw new RuntimeException("Accessing private constructor is prohibited. Use getInstance method instead");
    }
}

public static SingletonWithDoubleCheck getInstance(){
    if(INSTANCE == null){
        synchronized (SingletonWithDoubleCheck.class) {
            if(INSTANCE == null){
                INSTANCE = new SingletonWithDoubleCheck();
            }
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

}

Which one is better?

I feel we can access the private constructor with Reflection in first implementation where as second implementation is safe (From Reflection attack).

However, I am not going to use any of these in my production code, I will use ***enum*** instead. But out of these two, isn't the first implementation is broken when considered Reflection attack?

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: The singleton design pattern is not intended, in general, to withstand some kind of deliberate "attack". If someone is using reflection to expose a private constructor, it is their responsibility to know if what they are doing contravenes the intended use of the code.

Comment: The second one is unsafe, as posted. This has been hashed and rehashed. I agree completely with khelwood. A singleton is a design (anti-)pattern. Not a security tool. If someone has access to your code, he can do anything using reflection.

Comment: @JBNizet AFAIK it was fixed in Java 5.0 if you used a `volatile` field, but it shows that it's error prone.

Comment: Consider avoiding singletons 99% of the time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes, with volatile. But as posted, it's unsafe. And indeed it's so easy to mess up that it should be avoided, especially when there are better alternatives. Singletons should be avoided anyway, in general.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree. IMHO Singletons should only be stateless where ever possible. e.g. implementations of a strategy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are overly complicated.  The first was the best option before Java 5.0, however the second was never a good option. It didn't work before Java 5.0, it requires a `volatile` field and after this version you could use `enum`

I prefer using an `enum` to define a class with exactly one instance. It is a `final` class, thread safe, lazy loaded, and has a `private` constructor.

```
enum Singleon {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

The double locking singleton is only useful if you must provide configuration information in it's construction. In this case, I prefer to use Dependency Injection to provide/configure singletons and only have stateless Singletons which don't require configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Neither are good - and attempting to compare them using different scales is counter-productive.

The first is unnecessarily complex and, as you say, is open to reflection hacking, but so is the other one, just slightly less so.

The second uses a `synchronized` which comes with a cost.

Comment: Any lazy loaded solution needs a lock of some kind. Using a `final` field means there is no cost (not even a check) after the object has been initialised.